# My emulators don't use the same database, this will happen too if i install my app on different devices?

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio

I've been developing a resource managing app and my emulators won't use the same database. Everytime I'm using a different emulator, the database is different. All these things happen locally. Is this the way it suppose to happen?

I would like some answers on how SQLite databases work locally and how can I use the same one for different emulators/ devices.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQlite is an embedded database, every device will have it's own unique database (in short it's just a file).

However you can provide a pre-existing database.

You create the database (perhaps using an android device or using an SQLite tool, there's quite a few available some free e.g. DB Brwoser for SQLite, Navicat).

You then copy the resultant file (file name = database name) into the assets folder and before opening the database have a process that copies the file into the location and thus that copied file gets opened. The copy process can be simplified using [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

- *Note SQLiteAssethelper expects the file to be in a folder named databases in the assets folder.*

Noting that with the above each database itself will still be unique to the device, so if you change it on a device, that db will from then on be unique to the device.

If you need to share a single database, i.e. where changes made by a device are reflected on all devices, then you'd need *(not necessarily true, however there could be a great deal of work to manage such changes using SQLite)* to use a single server based database , perhaps Firebase (google's offering) or say have MySQL (there's a plethora of such server-client offerings).

You may find [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) useful in determining whether or not SQLite suits.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite databases are files local to the device.  To share data between devices you'd need to either implement a dedicated database on the 'net someplace that all devices can access, or (less desirable) a mechanism to synchronize each device.  I'd avoid the second option and investigate the first.

Comment: Great, but what do you specifically mean by dedicated database on the 'net someplace' ?

Comment: @LaviniaRotaru Exactly that; a database that all clients would talk to.